# Oracle SQL Retrieve dates within 2 weeks

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I'm trying to return information on cars in my table 'Cars' which have MOT's due within the next 2 weeks.
MOTDUE has been defined as `to_date('2015-03-25', 'yyyy-mm-dd');`

```
SELECT * FROM Cars WHERE MOTDUE = CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '2' WEEK;
```

just gives me "missing or invalid datetime field" error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you mean by "within the next two weeks" and assuming that the datatype of the `MOTDUE` column is `DATE`, then the following ought to give you what you need (or at least, allow you to amend appropriately):

```
select *
from   cars
where  motdue < trunc(sysdate) + 14
and    motdue >= trunc(sysdate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Cars WHERE MOTDUE = CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '14' DAY;
```

Comment: I've tried this and it no longer gives me an error, but it is also just returning nothing. Even though I know there is a car with MOTDUE in 2 days. Thanks.

Comment: The reason for that is that you're querying for motdue dates that equal a single date 14 days into the future. You're not querying for a range.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of `INTERVAL`s in Oracle - `YEAR TO MONTH` and `DAY TO SECOND`. So `YEAR`, `MONTH`, `DAY`, `HOUR`, `MINUTE` and `SECOND` are all valid increments. `WEEK`, unfortunately, is not (nor is `FORTNIGHT`, sadly). The ANSI standard way of doing this would be something like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM cars
 WHERE motdue >= CURRENT_DATE
   AND motdue < CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '14' DAY;
```

The problem with the above is that in Oracle, the ANSI-standard `CURRENT_DATE` doesn't adhere to the ANSI standard - it has a time portion just like `SYSDATE`. That's fine if you don't want to truncate dates at midnight.